# Rearranging two columns so that like elements are in one column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a problem which seems very easy. I just cannot think of how to search for a function which does this (or a way to find a similar question which has already been asked :-/ ). I currently have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
sp1                           sp2                            dist
Viola_canadensis_ott1089589 Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   8.043604e-311
Viola_nuttallii_ott203476   Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   6.702821e-311
Parnassia_fimbriata_ott1035577  Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   4.691921e-311
Paxistima_myrsinites_ott381954  Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   4.692195e-311
Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Sibbaldia_procumbens_ott176706  1.340783e-311
Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Fragaria_virginiana_ott1004791  2.680745e-311
Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Fragaria_vesca_ott852873    2.681018e-311
Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Geum_rossii_ott255461   2.681292e-311
```

This frame only has 3 columns and ca. 11000 rows. Note that I have 50 species that I want to 'move' partially to the sp1 column in the same manner as this species and ca. 250 species to move to the sp2 column; I already have these 50 species in a vector.

what I want to do is re-arrange the data frame so that it looks like this:

```
sp1                           sp2                            dist
Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott78213    Viola_canadensis_ott1089589 8.043604e-311
Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott78213    Viola_nuttallii_ott203476   6.702821e-311
Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott78213    Parnassia_fimbriata_ott1035577  4.691921e-311
Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott78213    Paxistima_myrsinites_ott381954  4.692195e-311
Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Sibbaldia_procumbens_ott176706  1.340783e-311
Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Fragaria_virginiana_ott1004791  2.680745e-311
Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Fragaria_vesca_ott852873    2.681018e-311
Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Geum_rossii_ott255461   2.681292e-311
```

I know this must be quite simple with dplyr!!!! I just have not come across a problem like this before.

Here is a longer example if it is needed:

```
key_species <- c("Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136", "Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293")

        sp1                            sp2                                 dist
    Aquilegia_elegantula_ott668865  Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293  6.703914e-312
    Aquilegia_coerulea_ott192307    Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293  6.703914e-312
    Corydalis_caseana_ott3944909    Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293  6.703914e-312
    Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293  Selaginella_densa_ott1095392    6.701177e-312
    Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293  Selaginella_scopulorum_ott5923066   6.701177e-312
    Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293  Blepharostoma_trichophyllum_ott390604   1.340235e-311
    Viola_canadensis_ott1089589 Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   8.043604e-311
    Viola_nuttallii_ott203476   Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   6.702821e-311
    Parnassia_fimbriata_ott1035577  Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   4.691921e-311
    Paxistima_myrsinites_ott381954  Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   4.692195e-311
    Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Sibbaldia_procumbens_ott176706  1.340783e-311
    Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Fragaria_virginiana_ott1004791  2.680745e-311
    Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Fragaria_vesca_ott852873    2.681018e-311
    Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Geum_rossii_ott255461   2.681292e-311
```

Desired outcome:

```
        sp1                            sp2                                 dist
    Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293  Aquilegia_elegantula_ott668865  6.703914e-312
    Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293  Aquilegia_coerulea_ott192307    6.703914e-312
    Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293   Corydalis_caseana_ott3944909   6.703914e-312
    Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293  Selaginella_densa_ott1095392    6.701177e-312
    Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293  Selaginella_scopulorum_ott5923066   6.701177e-312
    Erythronium_grandiflorum_ott653293  Blepharostoma_trichophyllum_ott390604   1.340235e-311
    Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott78213    Viola_canadensis_ott1089589 8.043604e-311
    Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott78213    Viola_nuttallii_ott203476   6.702821e-311
    Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott78213    Parnassia_fimbriata_ott1035577  4.691921e-311
    Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott78213    Paxistima_myrsinites_ott381954  4.692195e-311
    Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Sibbaldia_procumbens_ott176706  1.340783e-311
    Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Fragaria_virginiana_ott1004791  2.680745e-311
    Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Fragaria_vesca_ott852873    2.681018e-311
    Dasiphora_fruticosa_ott782136   Geum_rossii_ott255461   2.681292e-311
```

Sorry if this is a repost, I just really cannot think of a good way to formulate a search to find similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try creating new `sp` columns rather than modifying the ones you have in place. Then, when they look good, you can remove the old columns and rename the new ones.

```
data %>%
  mutate(new_sp1 = case_when(
      sp1 %in% key_species ~ sp1,
      sp2 %in% key_species ~ sp2,
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    ),
    new_sp2 = case_when(
      sp1 %in% key_species ~ sp2,
      sp2 %in% key_species ~ sp1,
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
)
```